# how do i make music play when i open a GUI

Tags: java, swing, audio, javasound

So i want to get a game that i'm making to start playing music when i open it. i have never done anything like this before, so i was wondering on some advice. i couldnt find any comprehensible things online, considering im a noob, so if you could do this and explain it pretty well that would be amazing. thanks! oh, i can post any info you need on the program.

the main class looks like:

```
package com.game.main.window;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public abstract class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

public static JFrame frame = new JFrame();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    createWindow();
}

public static void createWindow() {
    ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel(
            new ImageIcon(
                    "C:\\Users\\Austin\\Pictures\\My Pictures\\Le Parkour\\ABC0001.jpg")
                    .getImage());

    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.setJMenuBar(MenuBar.menuBarCreator());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setTitle("*Game Title* Beta 0.0.1 ADMINISTRATOR VERSION");
    frame.setSize(ImagePanel.img.getWidth(null),
            ImagePanel.img.getHeight(null));
    frame.setLocation(100, 100);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Playing a `Clip`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) code in the JavaSound info. page.

Obtain an URL to the sound embedded in the game Jar, using something like:

```
URL urlToExplosion = this.getClass().getResource("/path/to/boom.wav ");
```

### Edit 1

```
frame.setSize(ImagePanel.img.getWidth(null),
        ImagePanel.img.getHeight(null));
```

Bad, bad, bad.  Does not take into account the frame decorations.  `ImagePanel` should set a `preferredSize()` equal to the size of the image.  Since it is probably an `ImageObserver`, `this` can be used in place of `null` when getting the image Width x Height.  After that, simply add the image panel to the frame and call.

```
// set the frame to the smallest size needed to display the content
frame.pack();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to investigate [java concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) and in particular [concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). You can run the music in a background thread, but don't forget to stop it, when you exits from the application!

Comment: alright. well that really didnt help. the links dont have any examples or anything :"(

Comment: @wbAnon: you've got to be kidding. The links aren't going to give you the whole bit ready for you to plug into your program, but they explain Swing concurrency with examples without which your music attempt will not work. If you need further help though, you'd better let us know *specifically* where you're stuck and what you've tried.

Comment: @wbAnon: And you can find information on how to play sound in your Java program by looking at some of the related questions to the right, including [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259077/playing-game-music-in-java-how-to-stop-the-stream-of-data). But to use this with Swing, you'll still need to understand Swing Concurrency as per the links in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the [Java Media Framework](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html) in order to play music and such media, not too sure on the capabilities of MP3 though since I haven't tried, I believe there are more open source alternatives around but this should do the trick.

You can download it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-142937.html) and check out the documentation [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-135173.html).
Here is a [list of the formats](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/formats-138492.html) it currently supports in case the links end up wasting you time

Comment: As mentioned in the first link in my answer, the JMF is not needed in order to play short clips, but for MP3 support, it does require the plug-in (also mentioned in that page).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution might look like this:

```
public void playSound(final String file) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Applet.newAudioClip(getClass().getResource(file)).play();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Place a wav file next to your class, or in another package and change the getResource method, and invoke:

```
playSound("filename.wav");
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/14083-incredibly-easy-way-to-play-sounds/).
Just make sure to run this on a separate thread and stop the song when you exit, as stated above.
Also, just a tip:

```
ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel(
        new ImageIcon(
                "C:\\Users\\Austin\\Pictures\\My Pictures\\Le Parkour\\ABC0001.jpg")
                .getImage());
```

You should not do this. If you're distributing the application, the path won't be found and the image icon won't be displayed. You should create a folder that contains the resources and then use that path like so:

```
ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel(
    new ImageIcon("./resources/ABC0001.jpg").getImage());
```

So that the application will know where to look for the image.

Comment: `AudioClip` will not work in an application, and runs its own thread.  Also the advice about obtaining an image should have mentioned `getResource()` & is still effectively the wrong way to go about loading an embedded application resource.

Comment: ah. that would make sense (the tip) thanks for that. im currently looking at the link. ill have to fix that. thanks again for the tip